# How payment api's can bill automatically?

Tags: android, paypal, stripe-payments, payment, in-app-billing

Is there Mobile API for Android that have an option to charge clients automatically or in the end of the month? And also can handle wallet information? (I don't want to keep card information on my own server)

For example taxi, Lime (scooters) apps that charges automatically in the end of ride (card information was entered before), or even Google Ads that charges in the end of the month.

Which payment services they are use? Someone familiar?

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal on Android, a partial answer would be the Native SDK: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/ (not the web Checkout SDK referenced in another answer)

This does not address recurring billing / future transactions, however. For that with PayPal you need a feature called 'reference transactions' to be able to save or vault a billing agreement with each user. The PayPal business account owner can contact PayPal's general support (not their technical support) to inquire about enabling reference transactions with their service, and explain the business need for it. On review, PayPal may or may not approve the request, which is necessary for auto billing.

Answer (score 0):

Most merchant services should provide you with one. Here is paypals, but you would only want to use it if paypal is your merchant.

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK

Really, you should contact your merchant services (the company you are running the credit cards through)